# extract the day in a specific format from a date_range

Tags: python, date, pandas

I want to get a list with only the 'day' from this list with dates. I generated the dates with `pd.date_range` and then transformed it into a string.

```
date = '20170101'
fecha = pd.date_range(date , periods = 6, freq = 'D')
fecha = pd.Series(fecha.format())

print fecha[2][8:10]

for i in fecha:
    print fecha[i][8:10]
```

this throws `KeyError: '2017-01-01'`

From my understanding this `for loop` should iterate over the list and get the 2 digits for the day.
The reason why I am doing this is because I need to create dates with this format `'2017-4-4'` (so there is only one digit for numbers below 10)

Can somebody help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a datetime str using `dt.strftime`, then cast to `str` using `astype(str)`, then split on `'-'` cast to `int` to get rid of the leading `0`, you then cast back to `str` so we can then join the datetime components back together again:

```
In [105]:    
new_fecha = fecha.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').str.split('-',expand=True).astype(int).astype(str)
new_fecha[0] + '-' + new_fecha[1] + '-' + new_fecha[2]

Out[105]:
0    2017-1-1
1    2017-1-2
2    2017-1-3
3    2017-1-4
4    2017-1-5
5    2017-1-6
dtype: object
```

It looks like your `fecha` is a `DatetimeIndex` this doesn't need `.dt`:

```
new_fecha = fecha.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').str.split('-',expand=True).astype‌​(int).astype(str)
```

So the above should work

Comment: I tried this code, but I got the error `AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'dt'`

Comment: remove `.dt`: `new_fecha = fecha.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').str.split('-',expand=True).astype(int).astype(str)`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access keys in your `fecha` which do not exist. This is happening at:

```
for i in fecha:
    print fecha[i][8:10]
```

(and probably here: `print fecha[2][8:10]` as well)
The cause is that `i` is not an index of `fetcha` but an item inside it.

Change it to:

```
for i in fecha:
    print i[8:10]
```

or

```
for i in range(len(fecha)):
    print fecha[i][8:10]
```

Answer (score 1):

The fix is simple, but I'm going to attempt to explain what you've done.

You made a variable named `fecha` that is a `pandas.Series` object with an index ranging from `0` to `5` and values which are strings that look like dates:

```
print(fecha)

0    2017-01-01
1    2017-01-02
2    2017-01-03
3    2017-01-04
4    2017-01-05
5    2017-01-06
dtype: object
#      ^
# Notice dtype object.  Usually indicative of strings.
```

Now when you iterate with the `for` loop, are you iterating through the index?  Or the values?  In other words, what is `i`?

Let's print and see

```
for i in fecha:
    print(i)

2017-01-01
2017-01-02
2017-01-03
2017-01-04
2017-01-05
2017-01-06
```

Ahhhh!  Those are the string values and not the indices.  Ok, now that we know this we can explain why `fecha[i]` didn't work.  That's because the `[]` on a `pandas.Series` will attempt to grab the value from `fecha` whose index is `i`.  But! `i` is the value and **not** the index.

Here are some various ways to rework this issue:

***Option 1***

```
for i in fecha:
    print(i[8:10])

01
02
03
04
05
06
```

***Option 2***
*[`iteritems`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iteritems.html)*

```
for i, v in fecha.iteritems():
    print(fecha[i][8:10])

01
02
03
04
05
06
```

***Option 3***
*[`.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html) [also See This Link for strftime](http://strftime.org)*
*Skip the series object and print from the datetime index*

```
for d in pd.date_range(date, periods=6):
    print(d.strftime('%d'))

01
02
03
04
05
06
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, so when I do `Fecha[i][8:10]` I am calling to the value which is in the index [2], that's why it doesn't work when I put it inside the `for loop`

Comment: `fecha[something]` looks for the `something` in `fecha.index` and returns the corresponding value.  `fecha[i]` looks for `i` in the `fecha.index`  However, `i` is the value itself and is not in the index.  `i` takes on the values because you iterated over `fecha`.  My answer gives various ways to iterate and reference appropriately.